# How to implement linked list type structure in C#?

Tags: .net, linked-list

I have a requirement for linked list type traversing in c#, What structure i should use for my project
Please suggest..

Answer (score 5):

eh, a `System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<T>` maybe? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx

Comment: Unless requirement is to reinvent the wheel - it's better to use ready structure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some examples

[C# Generics Recipes—Implementing a Linked List](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Generics_Recipes%E2%80%94Implementing_a_Linked_List)

[Linked Lists](http://www.functionx.com/csharp1/examples/linkedlist.htm)

[Using Linked List in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jeradus/UsingLinkedListInCS11102005005525AM/UsingLinkedListInCS.aspx)

Comment: And a book - Data structures and algorithms using c#, http://www.amazon.com/Data-Structures-Algorithms-Using-C/dp/0521670152